# Jupyter Lab not shutting down despite there being no running notebooks shown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run Jupyter Lab but I noticed that I can't shut down the previous session. When I run Jupyter Lab, I do the following

```
jupyter-lab --no-browser --ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

in my Linux server and paste the output address to a Chrome browser. Normally when I'm done and I shut down the terminal everything works fine, but now it's saying:

```
Shutdown this Jupyter server (y/[n])? y
[C 2021-05-25 20:15:41.324 ServerApp] Shutdown confirmed
[I 2021-05-25 20:15:41.326 ServerApp] Shutting down 2 kernels
[I 2021-05-25 20:15:41.327 ServerApp] Kernel shutdown: abcdefgh-a891-4be3-b4ae-ee88ca5ff450
[I 2021-05-25 20:15:41.330 ServerApp] Kernel shutdown: ijklmnop-358b-4a24-be8d-214046ffd5eb
[I 2021-05-25 20:15:41.937 ServerApp] Shutting down 0 terminals
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> I get the following message:

```
[C 2021-05-26 08:24:45.648 ServerApp] received signal 2, stopping
```

and nothing happens afterwards. Running `jupyter notebook list` returns nothing as well.

Would anyone have any idea what the problem may be, and how I could shut down my Jupyter Lab session?

Comment: I think the right command could be `jupyter server list` if you are running on ServerApp. What happens if you press ctrl + C multiple times in short succession?

Comment: I already killed the tmux session that was running that Jupyter Lab, so the problem's  "solved" now, but yes it does seem that `jupyter server list` may be the appropriate command. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> multiple times I get that "received signal 2" message that many times, with no response afterwards.